# Issue with deep testing components in Angular and accessing html with debugElement

Tags: angular, jestjs, angular-test

I have a hierarchy of components in my angular app which is as follows:

`BookmarkContainer` has the following child components:

- `BookmarksListComponent`
- `CreateBookmarkComponent`

`BookmarksListComponent` has a `ngFor` of `BookmarkItemComponent`

I am trying to access the template of `BookmarkItemComponent` from the test of the `BookmarkContainer` using `DebugElement` and its `query()` method.

Here is the code for `BookmarkContainer`:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-bookmarks-container',
  templateUrl: './bookmarks.container.html',
  styleUrls: ['./bookmarks.container.scss']
})
export class BookmarksContainerComponent implements OnInit {
  bookmarks$: Observable<Bookmark[]>;
  newBookmark: Bookmark;
  deletedBookmarkId: number;

  constructor(private bookmarkService: BookmarkService) {}

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.setBookmarks();
  }

  private setBookmarks() {
    this.bookmarks$ = this.bookmarkService
      .currentUser()
      .pipe(
        mergeMap(session => this.bookmarkService.search({ account: session.user.uid }))
      );
  }
}
```

Here is the corresponding test:

```
describe('BookmarkContainerComponent', () => {
  let component: BookmarksContainerComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<BookmarksContainerComponent>;
  let httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  const aBookmark: Bookmark = {
    id: 42,
    title: 'a bookmark',
    url: 'http://www.example.com',
    account: '1'
  };
  const anotherBookmark: Bookmark = {
    id: 43,
    title: 'another bookmark',
    url: 'http://www.example.fr',
    account: '1'
  };

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
      declarations: [BookmarksContainerComponent, BookmarksListComponent, BookmarkItemComponent, CreateBookmarkComponent],
    }).compileComponents();
  }));

  beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookmarksContainerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });

  it('should create', () => {
    expect(component).toBeTruthy();
  });

  it('should search bookmarks', fakeAsync(() => {
    const sessionRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/system/connect');
    sessionRequest.flush({ user: { uid: '1' } });

    const bookmarksRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/bookmarks_link/search');
    bookmarksRequest.flush([aBookmark, anotherBookmark]);

    //Here I am not sure how to access the li(s) from the BookmarkItemComponent
    const item = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(BookmarkItemComponent));

});
```

I have tried to access the `li(s)` from the `BookmarkItemComponent` but without success: `item` is always `null`. I suspect it has something to do with the level of nesting of the `BookmarkItemComponent`...  Can someone please help?

**edit**:

Template for `BookmarkContainer`:

```
<app-bookmarks-list
  [bookmarks]="bookmarks$ | async"
  [newBookmark]="newBookmark"
  [updatedBookmark]="updatedBookmark"
  [deletedBookmark]="deletedBookmarkId"
  (deleteBookmarkEvt)="confirmDeleteBookmark($event)"
  (updateBookmarkEvt)="openUpdateForm($event)">
</app-bookmarks-list>
...
```

Template for `BookmarksListComponent`:

```
<ng-container *ngFor="let bookmark of bookmarks">
  <div class="bookmark">
    <div class="">
      <ul class="bookmark-list">
        <app-bookmark-item
          [bookmark]="bookmark"
          (deleteBookmarkEvt)="deleteBookmark($event)"
          (updateBookmarkEvt)="updateBookmark($event)"
        >
        </app-bookmark-item>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</ng-container>
```

Template for `BookmarkItemComponent`:

```
<li class="bookmark-item bookmark-item-{{ bookmark.id }}">
  <span class="bookmark-icon"></span>
  <span class="bookmark-text">
    <a href="{{ bookmark.url }}" target="_blank" title="{{ 'BOOKMARKS.OPEN' | translate}}">
    {{bookmark.title}}
    </a>
  </span>
  <span class="bookmark-actions">
    <a title="{{ 'GLOBAL.UPDATE' | translate}}" (click)="updateBookmark(bookmark)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
    </a>
    <a title="{{ 'GLOBAL.DELETE' | translate}}" (click)="deleteBookmark(bookmark.id)">
      <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove "></i>
    </a>
  </span>
</li>
```

Comment: Just for a sanity check, could you post the HTML template as well?

Comment: @garbear I have added the relevant templates

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to see the http response data appear in the DOM, you need to execute a `fixture.detectChanges()` after your `request.flush(...)`. Also, I would remove the `fakeAsync` wrap. It should not be needed.

E.g.,

```
it('should search bookmarks', function() {
    const sessionRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/system/connect');
    sessionRequest.flush({ user: { uid: '1' } });

    const bookmarksRequest = httpTestingController.expectOne('/api/bookmarks_link/search');
    bookmarksRequest.flush([aBookmark, anotherBookmark]);

    // add detectChanges here
    fixture.detectChanges();

    // item should be defined now.
    const item = fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(BookmarkItemComponent));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Can you try adding `async` on beforeEach?

```
beforeEach(async() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(BookmarksContainerComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    httpTestingController = TestBed.inject(HttpTestingController);
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

Comment: Hello @gaurav  No luck with the `async` either... I have tried as suggested. Item is still null.

Comment: I am having the similar setup. With async on ```beforeEach``` and ```fixture.detectChanges()``` before ```fixture.debugElement.query(By.directive(BookmarkItemComponent))``` is giving me actual element. Otherwise, I am also getting null.

Comment: I use jest. Does it make any difference ?

Comment: It's the same thing with the jest for me.